# Django serializer for .count()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make server-side table pagination and for this i've need object's count. So the problem is that i get error when trying to get this value because of serializer (`'int' object is not iterable`) i dont khow how to create serializer that returns this value. Below is the usual serializer for the model and of course it doesn't work properly.

**views.py**

```py
class CountItem(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Item.objects.count()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
```

**Serializer.py**

```py
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Use this `queryset = Item.objects.all()`

Comment: @shafik for what? I dont need all objects, all I need is their number.

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

Comment: What do you mean by "their number"? Just their id's? you can use `values` or `values_list` for that

Comment: @Sayse I meant "quantity", sorry

Comment: I don't think you need a `ListApiView` at all, you just need a straight forward basic view

Comment: @Sayse Well, I'll get rid of the serializer, but can you give me an example of how it should look?

Answer (score 2):

The result is paginated by default, simply fix your `queryset` value to contain a valid `QuerySet` object, instead of an integer, which is returned by `Item.objects.count()`:

```
class CountItem(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
```

The API endpoint should accept `"limit"`, `"offset"` query parameters and the response should contain the `"count"`, `"next"`, `"previous"` values by default if you add this config to your django settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': "25"
}
```

Comment: Yeah, ty, that solves my problem, but it's worth mentioning that it's not done by default, it's necessary to add `REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': "your int value here"
}` to settings.py